# Micro SD not being found on phone or pc after replacing

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery

My micro SD card filled up from pictures on my Galaxy S3 and previous phone. I went out and bought a larger capacity card to replace it. When I put the full card in my laptop to transfer the pictures, at first it worked. When I went to open the card, I could not find it anywhere on my laptop. I removed it and put it back in my phone and it is now saying the card is damaged. I have tried both multiple times, even in my camera, and still have not been able to find my pictures.

What can I do to find my pictures again and safely?

Comment: You might want to check [questions tagged external-sd and data-recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-sd+data-recovery) for what helped others in the same situation. If none of those 12 questions (including their answers) helped, please update your question with the new details, i.e. what you tried and where you got stuck. Thanks!